# Esperar uma função assíncrona terminar para continuar

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu consigo esperar uma função assíncrona terminal para continuar o código?

Eu tenho uma função assíncrona com um try/catch e quero pegar o erro para tratar.

```
Login(BuildContext context) async { 
try {
      FirebaseUser _login = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pass))
          .user;

      if (_login != null) {
        userid = _user.uid;
        Modular.to.pushNamed('/inicial');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      msge = e.code;
    }
  }
```

Quando chamo  a função e tento pegar o msge ele retorna null, fiz alguns testes e pelo que entendi ela retorna null pois ela ainda não havia terminado.

Tem alguma forma de pegar esse dado?

Comment: Uma função assíncrona sempre retorna um objeto do tipo `Future`. O operador `await` espera pela resolução desse `Future` e pega o resultado dele. Se você está recebendo `null`, então `null` é o resultado do `Future`, você está esperando corretamente, o resultado é que está vazio mesmo.

Comment: Mas essa função eu uso para verificar o login certo? Quando o email está errado o firebase retorna 'EMAIL_INVALID' que é o e.code, mas o que deve estar acontecendo é, quando ele chega no msge = e.code o e.code é null pois o await não retornou ainda. Seria isso?

Answer (score 1):

Apena relembrando, as funções devem sempre começar com letras minúsculas (lower-case).

Em relação ao teu problema, acredito que você está tentando capturar o `user` antes da função `signInWithEmailAndPassword` retornar algo, sendo assim, ao tentar acessar o valor de uma variável nula causará um outro erro diferente da validação do firebase.

Tente modificar sua função da seguinte forma:

```
  void login(BuildContext context) async { 
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    try {
      await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();

      if (user != null) {
        userid = user.uid;
        Modular.to.pushNamed('/inicial');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      msge = e.code;
    }
  }
```

A sua propriedade `msge` somente receberá um valor caso o `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` retorne algum dos erros já pré-definidos no package.

**Explicando**

O `await` faz com que a aplicação aguarde a chamada assíncrona terminar para que a execução do bloco daquela função continue.

Então se você está utilizando a propriedade `msge` em um outro lugar, muito provavelmente ela está sendo retornada NULA pois ainda não deu tempo de ser alimentado pelo método `login`.

Comment: Cara valeu pela explicação e pelos toques, acho que entedi, eu chamo essa função em outro arquivo mas acho que o meu erro é chamar a função e logo depois dar o debugPrint(login.msge) e sai null, acredito que o erro esteja ai, vou tentar dar uma estudada e ver se encontro o que pode ser.